# Nuxt content blog, article update without redeployment

Tags: nuxt.js, web-frontend

I'm currently building a Nuxt app and we might be adding a blog to it. Is there a way to use the [Nuxt content](https://content.nuxtjs.org/) module to create a blog where we don't have to redeploy the app to make changes to certain blog posts?

As I understand it you set .md, .yaml, etc. files to the content/ folder and the module serves it statically, but is there a way to serve those files from a different source like S3. The issue I'm having with redeployment is that I don't want to redeploy the entire app just to add/edit one post. The app is deployed on Heroku if that helps.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm in the same boat.

Comment: @RizaKhan I've posted the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution: headless CMS. We've decided to use GraphCMS as it had the best pricing options but there's a lot of options out there. There's even an article in the [vuejs cookbook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/serverless-blog.html) on how to implement an API based blog, but they are using ButterCMS that has a very limited free tier